# Gas In dip tube is missing in my corny-keg

Tags: corny-keg

I bought two used cornies. They're pin locks, and neither of them came with Gas tubes. Will everything still work? Or do I need to buy replacements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure they're not there? I ask because I have six pin lock kegs, and two of them have tiny gas dip tubes that are maybe a quarter of an inch long. (Just long enough to hold the O-ring.) They usually stick inside the gas post when I remove it. I can attest that these short dip tubes work just fine.

To answer your question, though, you will need dip tubes because the O-ring that creates the seal slides onto the dip tube. Without the dip tube, there's no O-ring. Without the O-ring, there's no seal.

Also, I'm not sure the poppet valve inside the post will function properly if the dip tube is missing. The gap left between the bottom of the poppet valve and the top of the nipple probably would allow the poppet valve to slide down out of position, leaving it incapable of creating a seal at the top of the post.

If you really don't have the dip tubes and just want to see what happens, you can try putting thread tape on the nipple, screwing the post on, pushing some gas in, and checking for leaks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I've checked both the hole and the post. I'll re-check, because they guy I bought the kegs from said he'd used one of them...

Comment: It looks like you're right. I think it's stuck *in* the keg. I looked closer and the whole for the gas peg looks like it has a rubber gasket on it. I think it's the o-ring. I"ll have to try prying it up tonight.

Comment: If it's not too stuck, you should be able to grasp the top edge of the dip tube with some needle-nose pliers and lift straight up on it. Good luck! Be careful when prying :)

Comment: The o-ring needed replacing anyway, so I used a knife to pry up, using the o-ring for leverage, rather than the tube. Thanks! For anyone in the future, it looks like the gas dip tubes are *so* short you can't feel them from the inside...Thus my mis-understanding.